# Disabling the page down function in wordpress posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a video player in my wordpress posts that uses the space bar to pause. The space bar triggers the page down function causing the page to scroll away from the video.

I used the following code to attempt to stop it, but it only disables use of the page down key:

```
    window.onkeydown=function(e){
 if(e.keycode==34){
   e.preventDefault();
}
}
```

Is there a way to stop the space bar doing this, Or to disable the page down function in wordpress posts?

Comment: That's not a WordPress "function", that's normal browser behaviour. It works on every site.

Comment: I see. Would there be a simple way to have it the scrolling stop after I've clicked into the html5 video, similar to youtube? I do like the space bar as the play/pause key.

Comment: I don't know what browser you are using, but usually (at least for me and for most video players) the space bar works exactly like you want it as long as the video player has the focus. Meaning: when I click on the video player i can play/pause with space. If I click outside of the video player and it hasn't the focus anymore the page scrolls.

Comment: What you could do: Check if you can control the video player with javascript. Then, use your `onkey` event, check if a video is playing, if yes, block the default action and toggle play/pause. If not, do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to disable the space keypress in the browser (which probably isn't recommended in a lot of situations for accessibility reasons), just add the `space` key code of 32 to your if statement:

```
window.onkeydown=function(e){
  if(e.keycode==34 || e.keycode==32){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I do like the space bar as the play/pause key, I want to avoid disabling the space bar key altogether.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that you would need to add a call to the video player to then keep the space bar operational as the play/pause key. What video player are you using?